# Find missing dates in Star Schema date table

Tags: sql, sql-server, dimension

I have a dimension table of dates.  It starts with 1900-01-01 and includes a day for every day up until 2199-12-31.  I need to find it is missed any date.

I have tried most every query on the internet.  My sql understanding is not good enough to break the query apart to understand.  Also, I do not have permission to write temp tables (working on it) so this has hindered some.

Here is one that I tried.  My column name is ShortDate. There is also a column longdate that I tried in comparison but no go. The table name is dimDate.

```
   {
    SELECT t1.ShortDate AS startOfGap, MIN(t2.ShortDate) AS endOfGap  
       FROM  
       (SELECT ShortDate = ShortDate + 1  FROM sampleDates tbl1  
          WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dimDates tbl2  
                          WHERE tbl2.ShortDate = tbl1.ShortDate + 1) 
          AND ShortDate <> (SELECT MAX(ShortDate) FROM dimDates)) 
    t1 
       INNER JOIN  
       (SELECT ShortDate = ShortDate – 1  FROM dimDates tbl1  
          WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dimDates tbl2  
                              WHERE tbl1.theDate = tbl2.theDate + 1) 
              AND ShortDate <> (SELECT MIN(ShortDate) FROM dimDates)) t2  
           ON t1.ShortDate <= t2.ShortDate 
           GROUP BY t1.ShortDate;
        }
```

I just get a multitude of errors with every query that I try.  Unfortunately,my logic isn't good enough to understand what SHOULD be in this query

I have tried this one:

```
SELECT  TOP 1
        DateShort + 1
FROM   dimDates mo
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    dimDates mi 
        WHERE   mi.DateShort = mo.DateShort + 1
        )
ORDER BY DateShort
```

but get an error that states 'conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2029-10-02' to data type int

Comment: Although not terribly efficient, you could use a self join based on the next date in sequence, then use a datediff to ascertain if the next day is more than 24 hours after the previous. That will find your gaps

Comment: ok thanks.  Let me look those up and give an attempt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A self join can be used in combination with a datediff to identify the gaps where days are missing. You'll get the idea.

```
 declare @test table (yourdate datetime);
 insert into @test
 values 
 ('2019-01-01'),
 ('2019-01-02'),
 ('2019-01-03'),
 ('2019-01-04'),
 ('2019-01-05'),
 ('2019-01-07')

 select t1.yourdate [firstdate], t2.yourdate [next date], 
 case when datediff(d,t1.yourdate,t2.yourdate) > 1 then 'flag' else 'ok' end [dayflag]
 from
 (
 select yourdate, row_number() over (order by yourdate) seq
 from @test
 )t1
 left join (select yourdate, row_number() over (order by yourdate) seq from @test) t2
 ON t1.seq = t2.seq - 1
```

Comment: oh my goodness, you are awesome.  Thank you.  This worked perfectly!

Comment: @Kat if this worked for you consider marking it as the answer. It rewards the person who posted this and lets others know you have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `lead()`:

```
select sd.*
from (select sd.*, lead(shortdate) over (order by shortdate) as next_shortdate
      from sampleDates sd
     ) sd
where next_shortdate <> dateadd(day, 1, shortdate);
```

This will not return strings of missing dates at the end of the period.  You can fix this with:

```
where next_shortdate <> dateadd(day, 1, shortdate) or
      (next_shortdate is null and shortdate < '2199-12-31'
```

You can also do this with a `join`:

```
select sd.*  -- the day before each group of missing dates
from sampleDates sd left join
     sampleDate sd_next
     on sd_next.shortdate = dateadd(day, 1, shortdate)
where sd_next.shortdate is null;
```

This version will return the last date in the table, so you might want to add:

```
where sd.shortdate <  '2199-12-31'
```